# Delete a node in a linked list by using dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, linked-list

I have the following method, and I want to delete `{5285831021: 'Hayes'}` from a list. How do I do by just passing `5285831021`?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None

class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insert(self, pair):
        if not isinstance(pair, Node):
            pair = Node(pair)
        if self.is_empty():
            self.head = pair
        else:
            current = self.head
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = pair
            pair.prev = current
        self.tail = pair

    def __str__(self):
        to_print = ''
        current = self.head
        while current:
            to_print += f'{current.data}<->'
            current = current.next
        if to_print:
            return f'[{to_print[:-3]}]'
        return '[]'
```

This is the method I created to delete a node by given key.

```
    def delete(self, key):
        pass

my_list = DoublyLinkedList()
my_list.insert({2363688062: 'Clark'})
my_list.insert({5598260087: 'Russell'})
my_list.insert({5285831021: 'Hayes'})
my_list.insert({5285234321: 'Henderson'})
my_list.insert({9447143408: 'Hamilton'})

my_list.delete(5285831021)
print(my_list)
```

Comment: You need to remove the `Node` from the `DoublyLinkedList` prior to deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def delete(self, value):
    curr = self.head
    while curr:
        if list(curr.data.keys())[0] == value:
            node_to_delete = curr.next
            curr.data = node_to_delete.data
            curr.next = node_to_delete.next
            return
        curr = curr.next
```

Comment: The problem with this edit is that it does not delete the last key in linked list. Your previous answer helped.
What if I don't do del(current)? It is also working fine, so why you use del keyword?

Comment: Glad it help, also sorry, but I'm new on answering Stack overflow questions, and I wanted to ask how do I check the previous edits from an answer (even if is not mine)?